# Docky isn't running!

Tags: 10.10, docky

Docky doesn't start, neither in the system startup (i have it as a startup application) nor when I start it manually. It stopped working yesterday.

I'm running ubuntu 10.10, and downloaded docky from the standard repos.

`docky --help | head -3` gives me this output:

```
* (/usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe:4184): WARNING *: The following assembly referenced from /usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe could not be loaded: Assembly: dbus-sharp-glib (assemblyref_index=13) Version: 1.0.0.0 Public Key: 5675b0c3093115b5 The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/usr/lib/docky/).

* (/usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe:4184): WARNING *: Could not load file or assembly 'dbus-sharp-glib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5675b0c3093115b5' or one of its dependencies. * (/usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe:4184): WARNING *: Missing method Init in assembly /usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe, type DBus.BusG Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dbus-sharp-glib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5675b0c3093115b5' or one of its dependencies. File name: 'dbus-sharp-glib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=56
```

Answer (score 1):

Docky needs the `libdbus-glib1.0-cil` package and it looks like you don't have it installed.

Install it by clicking the link above or by running the following in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib1.0-cil`

Comment: didn't work, docky hasn't been working since yesterday, it suddenly stopped.